# How much simulator time can I use towards a part 61 instrument rating?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, flight-simulator

I am doing Instrument Rating under part 61 with a CFII.

1. To meet the 50 hours cross country requirement (d 1), can I log some of the PIC time in a simulator?
2. There is a 20 hours limitation on the use of simulator (h 2). So, if I have 40 hours of simulator time and 15 of them are cross country, can I use those 15 hours towards the cross county requirement and the other 5 hours towards the 40 hours requirement (d 2)?

> (d) Aeronautical experience for the instrument-airplane rating. A
>   person who applies for an instrument-airplane rating must have logged:
>
> (1) Except as provided in paragraph (g) of this section, 50 hours of
>   cross-country flight time as pilot in command, of which 10 hours must
>   have been in an airplane; and
>
> (2) Forty hours of actual or simulated instrument time in the areas of
>   operation listed in paragraph (c) of this section, of which 15 hours
>   must have been received from an authorized instructor who holds an
>   instrument-airplane rating, and the instrument time includes:
>
> (i) Three hours of instrument flight training from an authorized
>   instructor in an airplane that is appropriate to the
>   instrument-airplane rating within 2 calendar months before the date of
>   the practical test; and
>
> (ii) Instrument flight training on cross country flight procedures,
>   including one cross country flight in an airplane with an authorized
>   instructor, that is performed under instrument flight rules, when a
>   flight plan has been filed with an air traffic control facility, and
>   that involves—
>
> (A) A flight of 250 nautical miles along airways or by directed
>   routing from an air traffic control facility;
>
> (B) An instrument approach at each airport; and
>
> (C) Three different kinds of approaches with the use of navigation
>   systems.
>
> (h) Use of full flight simulators or flight training devices. If the
>   instrument time was provided by an authorized instructor in a full
>   flight simulator or flight training device—
>
> (1) A maximum of 30 hours may be performed in that full flight
>   simulator or flight training device if the instrument time was
>   completed in accordance with part 142 of this chapter; or
>
> (2) A maximum of 20 hours may be performed in that full flight
>   simulator or flight training device if the instrument time was not
>   completed in accordance with part 142 of this chapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator doesn’t meet the definition of *aircraft*.

> §61.1   Applicability and definitions.
>
> Cross-country time means—
>
> (i) Except as provided in paragraphs (ii) through (vi) of this
> definition, time acquired during flight—
>
> (A) Conducted by a person who holds a pilot certificate;
>
> (B) Conducted in an aircraft;
>
> (C) That includes a landing at a point other than the point of
> departure; and
>
> (D) That involves the use of dead reckoning, pilotage, electronic
> navigation aids, radio aids, or other navigation systems to navigate
> to the landing point.
>
> (ii) For the **purpose of meeting the aeronautical experience
> requirements** (except for a rotorcraft category rating), for a private
> pilot certificate (except for a powered parachute category rating), a
> commercial pilot certificate, or an instrument rating, or for the
> purpose of exercising recreational pilot privileges (except in a
> rotorcraft) under §61.101 (c), time acquired during a flight—
>
> (A) Conducted in an **appropriate aircraft**;
>
> (B) That includes a point of landing that was at **least a straight-line
> distance of more than 50 nautical miles** from the original point of
> departure; and
>
> (C) That involves the use of dead reckoning, pilotage, electronic
> navigation aids, radio aids, or other navigation systems to navigate
> to the landing point.

Comment: Thanks. I got confused by the "of which 10 hours must have been in an airplane". If cross county = conducted in an aircraft, I am not sure why would they word it like that.

Comment: @user41786 There are aircraft other than airplanes. Consider someone with a lot of helicopter time, for instance, who is transitioning to airplanes.